# Allowing URL access only to logged-in users

Tags: python, django

I am getting started with the django framework and I created a simple website where the user first logs in and then is redirected to another page.

I tried typing the URL of the redirected page before logging in, and it loads. Instead, I want it to redirect back to the login page (home page).

I tried checking if the user is authenticated to view the page only if it is. It is written in the `views.py` file of the redirected page:

```
def index(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        return render(request, 'professors/index.html')
    else:
        return redirect('' % request)
```

- `professors/` is the URL of the redirected page
- `''` is the URL of the login page (home page)

***Update***

`views.py`:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

# Create your views here.
@login_required
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'professors/index.html')
```

`urls.py`:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path(r'', views.index, name='index')
];
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To restrict views to only logged in users use django's login required decorator

**views.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'professors/index.html')
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index')
]
```

If they are not logged in they will be redirected to your login page

Comment: I edited the code, but it is still allowing the access to the URL. Should that code be in `views.py`?

Comment: You may be already logged in, this method definitely works. And yes it should be in the views

Comment: I know I am not, because I check if I can access the admin page, and it pops the login form. If I was logged in, it would've allowed me to access the admin page.

Comment: Show me the ```urls.py``` and the ```views.py``` for that view

Comment: Updated post with `urls.py` and `views.py`

Comment: Did so, but it is still letting me access the page

Comment: I use this method my self every day, it does work. Without seeing all the code I can't help you more here. Feel free to share the rest of the code to my email che@superpay.it, I'll be happy to take a look.

Comment: I am going to post it on github and share the link here as soon as I am done

Comment: Github link: https://github.com/J-Kazama/rep1 `urls.py` and `views.py` are for the professors file (corresponds to the page which should not be opened if the user is not logged-in)

Comment: The issue is with this file rep1/proj1/urls.py you have not actually linked the other ```url.py``` files

Comment: How do I do that? I tried to google that but I did not find anything useful

Comment: Update: I see that even if I comment everything in the `views.py` in professors' file, everything works as is. And as importantly--I am totally confused

Comment: Putting ```path('home/', include('login.urls'))``` instead of ```path('home/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='login/sign.html'), name='login-website')``` made it work with the solution you provided. Thank you!