# Getting secure url for Files from Google Cloud Platform Storage using Django to Show on the frontend

Tags: python, django, google-cloud-platform

How can I safely get the web address of a file sent from the frontend to Google Cloud Platform (GCP) storage using Django, and then show it on the frontend for users without letting everyone see it? Any help with this would be really helpful.

Comment: can you elaborate your issue with reproducible steps what you have tried that didn't work , Also Check this [link](https://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backends/gcloud.html) Google storage section of Django Storages.

Comment: @SathiAiswarya How do I securely fetch and display the URL of a Django-uploaded file on Google Cloud Platform (GCP) storage without making it public?

Answer (score 1):

Create a GCS bucket “private-gcs” and ensure it is private while creating the bucket

Generate a [Signed URLs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls) and then send it to users. The person who has  the URL can access the underlying resource. If someone doesn't have that url, they won't be able to access the resource.

You specify an expiration time when you create the signed URL. Anyone who knows the URL can access the resource until the expiration time for the URL is reachedThe max duration allowed is 7 days when `private-key-file` is used. You can check more about creating signed url in this [document](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/signurl)

Also check this stackoverflow [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70936328/google-cloud-storage-upload-method-is-returning-signed-url-django-python) & [blog](https://medium.com/@mohammedabuiriban/how-to-use-google-cloud-storage-with-django-application-ff698f5a740f)

Comment: Is there a way to make sure that only users who are logged into our app can view file? In other words, just having the link shouldn't let anyone in; only people who are logged into our app should be able to see it.

Comment: @Ayaz Khan You can use django's `login_required` decorator to restrict views to only logged in user. check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56567590/18265638)

Comment: You are correct, but when we create a signed URL, if someone else obtains this URL, they will be able to access our file. How can we restrict access to the file? One way is to add the user to IAM (Identity and Access Management). Are there any other methods to achieve this?

Comment: IAM is the recommended method for controlling access to your resources.However, you can check more [Additional access control options](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control#additional_access_control_options)

Comment: @Ayaz Khan Have you check my above comment about additional access control options

Comment: @BadalaPrashanth Thank you for your response. However, I've discovered an alternative solution. It involves encrypting the link and sending it to the frontend along with a unique identifier. When the user on the frontend clicks on unique identifier name, the encrypted link will be decrypted on the backend. Subsequently, the file will be downloaded and sent back to the frontend user.